# scrollTo within a container and fixed header

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm having a tough time deciphering scrollTo's documentation. I can get it to work by scrolling the whole page via $.scrollTo, but what I'm hoping for is scrolling within a parent. I have a fixed header that I would like to set as the scroll to point.

This works:

```
$('#one_l').click(function () {
        $.scrollTo($('#one'), 500);
    });
```

This doesn't:

```
$('#one_l').click(function () {
        $('#feature_scroll').scrollTo($('#one'), 500);
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML/CSS? Seems to work in [this demo I set up](http://jsfiddle.net/uTPkL/).

Comment: Thanks freejosh. I compared your code to mine and realized after a bit that I had a typo in my CSS. Setting a height and an overflow value is key to getting this to work. I don't know why he doesn't just state this in his documentation.